# How to cann a method located in service form Ativity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to call my `getWord(String w)` function OnButtonClick, but when I do so my app crashes? Am I calling my `Service function` wrong?

**ListActivity.java**

```java
WordLeanerService WLService;
ServiceConnection WLConn;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(ListActivity.this,WordLeanerService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        setupConnectionToWLservice();
        searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Saving user's input in search field
                input = String.valueOf(editSearch.getText());

                //Checking if input is valid (not empty and only alphabet characters)
                if (!input.equals("") && (input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))) {
                    //Sending input to request
                    WLService.getWord(input);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.input_invalid_message_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
}
    private void setupConnectionToWLservice(){
        WLConn = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                bindService(new Intent(ListActivity.this,WordLeanerService.class),WLConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                //ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
                WLService = ((WordLeanerService.ServiceBinder)service).getService();
                //TODO: probably a good place to update UI after data loading
            }
            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
                //ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
                WLService = null;
            }
        };
    }
```

**WordLeanerService.java**

```java
public void getWord(String w) {
        Toast.makeText(this, w, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Logcat**

```java
2020-03-28 14:27:03.098 28186-28186/com.example.word_learner_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.word_learner_app, PID: 28186
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.word_learner_app.WordLeanerService.getWord(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.word_learner_app.ListActivity$1.onClick(ListActivity.java:78)
```

So the ERROR is: `WLService.getWord(input);`

Comment: When your app crashes you need to post the stack trace.

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs Did now.

Comment: You never initialized WLService. Also in Java it is common practice to name variables and methods in camelCase

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: `WordLearnerService wlService = new WordLearnerService();` or you can make the `getWord` method `static` and then do `WordLearnerService.getWord();`